# Spring boot - bootstrap and thymeleaf sort table

Tags: spring, spring-boot, bootstrap-4, thymeleaf

I have a spring boot app that uses thyemeleaf for html and boostrap for design.

I'm looking for a table that can do the following functions

1. Sort option in the header. Upon clicking it sort all rows according to the value of the particular col
2. Allow search of values in one particular row
3. Limit the rows showed in page. E.g. page 1 shows 30 rows, clicking on 2 shows 30 rows

I looked around and saw usage of Javascript but I'm not sure how to use Javascript. Any help if appreciated!

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<link rel="stylesheet"
    href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css"
    integrity="sha384-Vkoo8x4CGsO3+Hhxv8T/Q5PaXtkKtu6ug5TOeNV6gBiFeWPGFN9MuhOf23Q9Ifjh"
    crossorigin="anonymous">
<title>Home</title>
</head>
<body>



    <div class="jumbotron">
    
        <h1 class="display-4">Coronavius tracker application</h1>
    
        <p class="lead">This application tracks the coronavirus situation around the globe</p>

        <hr class="my-4">
        <div class="container">
    
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col">
                    <h3>
                    <p class="font-weight-bold">Total world cases</p>
                    <!--    p tag takes up the entire width -->
                    <p class="font-weight-bold" th:text="${worldCases}"></p>
                    </h3>
                </div>      
            
                <div class="col">
                        <h3>
                    <p class="font-weight-bold">Total world deaths</p>
                    <p class="font-weight-bold"th:text="${worldDeaths}"></p>
                    </h3>
                </div>
                <div class="col">
                <h3>
                    <p class="font-weight-bold">World population</p>
                    <p class="font-weight-bold" th:text="${worldPop}"></p>
                </h3>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>



    <table class="table table-striped">
        <thead>
            <tr>

                <th scope="col">County</th>
                <th scope="col">Total cases</th>
                <th scope="col">New cases</th>
                <th scope="col">Total deaths</th>
                <th scope="col">Population</th>

            </tr>
        </thead>

        <tbody>
            <tr th:each="item :${alldata}">
                <td th:text="${item.country}"></td>
                <td th:text="${item.totalCases}"></td>
                <td th:text="${item.newCases}"></td>
                <td th:text="${item.totalDeaths}"></td>
                <td th:text="${item.pop}"></td>

            </tr>

        </tbody>
    </table>


</body>
</html>
```

Comment: It's not clear what you are for asking, here, beyond a general request about how to use JavaScript. Can you narrow things down to something more specific? Take a look at [DataTables](https://datatables.net/), and other similar solutions - maybe that will help. (Otherwise, this question is too broad and may be closed.)

Comment: Since you don't know js, lets keep it to java, for each header that you want to click on you create a very simple onClick (you can do that in html) go to a /sort/byFooHeader. In your controller you sort the collection that stores the values, update the model, and reload the view.

Answer (score 1):

Using datatables, I was able to get the table with the desired function. My code is as attached

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<!-- To use thymeleaf -->
<html xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<link rel="stylesheet"
    href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css"
    integrity="sha384-Vkoo8x4CGsO3+Hhxv8T/Q5PaXtkKtu6ug5TOeNV6gBiFeWPGFN9MuhOf23Q9Ifjh"
    crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.19/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css">
    <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.19/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
    <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready( function () {
        $('#dataTable').DataTable();
    } );
    </script>
<title>Home</title>
</head> 
<body>


    <!--    Creates a big gray field  -->
    <div class="jumbotron">
        <!-- Big words -->
        <h1 class="display-4">Coronavirus tracker</h1>
        <!--   Big words description -->
        <p class="lead">Tracking this pandemic one at a time</p>
    <!--    Marks bottom part of jumbotron   -->
        <hr class="my-4">
        <div class="container">
        <!-- Gride layout with each col detonated by class ="col" -->
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col">
                    <h3>
                    <p class="font-weight-bold">Total world cases</p>
                    <!--    p tag takes up the entire width -->
                    <p class="font-weight-bold" th:text="${worldCases}"></p>
                    <p class="font-weight-bold" th:text="${percentage}"></p>
                    </h3>
                </div>      
            
                <div class="col">
                        <h3>
                    <p class="font-weight-bold">Total world deaths</p>
                    <p class="font-weight-bold"th:text="${worldDeaths}"></p>
                    </h3>
                </div>
                <div class="col">
                <h3>
                    <p class="font-weight-bold">World population</p>
                    <div class="font-weight-bold" th:text="${worldPop}"></div>
                </h3>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>


<!--    @id give id to the table and match the javascript
    @page-length to match the default entries per page
    @data-order to set the default way to display order. It is now 1st col in descending order -->
    <table class="table table-striped" id="dataTable" data-page-length='50' data-order='[[1, "desc"]]'>
        <thead>
            <tr>

                <th scope="col">County</th>
                <th scope="col">Total cases</th>
                <th scope="col">New cases</th>
                <th scope="col">Total deaths</th>
                <th scope="col">Population</th>

            </tr>
        </thead>

        <tbody>
            <tr th:each="item :${alldata}">
                <td th:text="${item.country}"></td>
                <td th:text="${item.totalCases}"></td>
                <td th:text="${item.newCases}"></td>
                <td th:text="${item.totalDeaths}"></td>
                <td th:text="${item.pop}"></td>

            </tr>

        </tbody>
    </table>


</body>
</html>
```